# Prove every 3-cycle of A4 has the form $g^2$

Tags: group-theory

Prove that every 3-cycle in $A_4$ has the from $g^2$ for some $g \in A_4.$

I really do not know where to start with this proof.
All I know is that A4 has order 12. There are 8, 3-cycles in A4. I also can see that every 3-cycle is equal to the composition a an element in A4 "squared." But I am not sure how to put it in a general sense.
Any methods of proceeding are helpful.

Comment: In any group if an  element $g$ has order $3$ then $(g^2)^2 = g$.

Comment: @BogaertsMarc this is an introductory course in group theory. That being said, I've never heard of this, but after some thought I see that it makes sense. I'll try and sketch out a formal proof for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\sigma$ be a 3-cycle. It is also an element of order $3$. (In $S_4$ and $A_4$ there are no other elements of order $3$). That means the group generated by it is of order 3, viz. $\{\sigma, \sigma^2, \sigma^3=id\}$. Now defining $g$ to be $\sigma^2$, it follows that $g^2=\sigma^4=\sigma^3\sigma=\sigma$.